# Reminder in Android doesn't repeat

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I'm trying to set a reminder in my Android app, which will go off on certain days at the same set time.
Everything works fine for the first alarm, but then it doesn't repeat, nor goes off for other days.

Following is the interface:

[image]

Clicking on "Save Changes", it will be called the scheduleAlarm method for each selected day:

```
private void scheduleAlarm(int dayOfWeek) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (dayOfWeek == 0)
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    else {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time_str[] = reminder_time.getText().toString().split(":");
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(time_str[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(time_str[1]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        Long weekly = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR / 12; //AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7;

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, weekly, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

As you can see in this version I was trying to repeat the alarm every 5 minutes (`Long weekly = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR / 12;`)

The notification service called when the alarm goes off is as follows:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
public NotifyService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this , Splash.class);
    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.NOTIFICATION), true);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notification_icon_ensafe);
    long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.reminder))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.reminder_body))
            .setLargeIcon(bm)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_ensafe)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle())
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

    NotificationManager notificationManager  = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Any idea why it is not working?

***EDIT***

As @Frank has suggested, I implemented a BroadcastReceiver, but it's never called.

In the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".synchro.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The class:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

List<Integer> selectedDays;
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

        **\\ STUFF HAPPENS HERE \\ **

    }
}
}
```

The broadcaster is initiated in the scheduleAlarm method listed above, as follows:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), BootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device goes off, all scheduled alarms are cancelled by the OS. Might that be your problem?

To solve this, you'll have to listen to device startups with a broadcast listener and schedule your alarms again when the device started broadcast comes in.

*** EDIT ***

All info you need is on this page: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Especially on "Start an Alarm When the Device Boots" section: "By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down. To prevent this from happening..."

It takes a bit of time to setup and test. Not a quicky.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This broadcast listener should be implemented in the NotifyService class which is called upon the OS wake?

Comment: Ok. so basically I have to reschedule the alarm via alarmManager in the BootReceiver, while the service will manage the alarm itself. Am I right?

Comment: I tried the way you suggested, but the BootReceiver is never called. I keep having the alarm go off the first time, but nothing happens after. I also tried to reschedule the alarm in the NotifyService class, but nothing happens. I'm gonna upload the updated code in my question. Could you please check if it is correct?

Comment: maybe android:enabled="false" should be true?

Comment: I also tried that road. It won't call it.
I seriously don't know what the hell is wrong there. But I solved the other way. Thanks anyway for your help (Y)

Comment: still if you restart your device all your alarms will be cancelled. but good luck anyways.

Comment: you were right. I managed to make everything works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the problem.

In the NotifyService class I was using the `onCreate()` method to reschedule the alarm. This method is called only the first time. After that only `onStartCommand` is called.
Managing these two methods I achieved a working AlarmAcheduler.